# Difficulty Understanding a Particular Usage of Abel's Theorem in the Wronskian

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

suppose I have some equation:
$$
\frac{dy^2}{dx^2} + (x^2-3x)y' + 12y = 0 
$$

(The above equation is just for example)

Using Abel's Theorem for the Wronskian:
$$
W(y_1, y_2)(x) = ce^{-\int p(x)~dx} 
$$

If I know the value of the Wronskian for some $x = a$, can I calculate the Wronskian for any value of $x$?

For instance, suppose I know for $x = 5$, $W(y_1, y_2) (5) = 27$
(I know this is not the case, but let's suppose), where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are some solution to the equation.

Consequently, can I solve for the constant C:

$27 = ce^{-\int x^2 - 3x~dx} , x = 5$

$27 = ce^{-\dfrac{x^3}{3} + \dfrac{3x^2}{2}} , x = 5$

$27 = ce^{-\dfrac{x^3}{3} + \dfrac{3x^2}{2}} , x = 5$

$27 = ce^{-\dfrac{25}{3}} $

$ c = 27e^{\dfrac{25}{3}} $

And hence, would I be able to solve for all W(y1, y2)(x)?